# Bounding the large semicircular contour in integrals like $\oint\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\, dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Considering the large semicircular arc $\Gamma$ in the upper half plane of $\oint{\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\,dz}$ using the Estimation Lemma with $z=Re^{i\theta}, \theta\in[0,\pi]$ means :

$$\sup\left|\frac{e^{iRe^{i\theta}}}{Re^{i\theta}}\right|= \sup\frac{|e^{iR(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}|}{R}=\sup\frac{|e^{-R\sin\theta}|}{R}$$

How can the numerator be simplified? In the range $\sin\theta$ can be positive, and as $R\to\infty$ the original semicircle wouldn’t vanish. If the integral inequality $\left|\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)\,dx}\right|\leq\int_{a}^{b}{|f(x)|\, dx}$ is used you can double the integral and use $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as the bound instead, and then use Jordan’s inequality. But the Estimation lemma follows from the integral inequality, so it must still be possible to bound the expression.

EDIT : Yes, Jordan's Lemma can be used, but I was more interested in how this extends to the definition of the Estimation Lemma and the absolute value (given it does not contain an integral, but rather an upper bound)

Comment: Perhaps you would find some of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDiC_tZdEp8) useful? Skimming through it, it looks like the part around 4 minutes is what you need.

Comment: Re your edit: What exactly are you looking for if not a demonstration that the integral converges to zero for $R \to \infty$? The numerator $|e^{-R\sin\theta}|$ is equal to $e^{-R\sin\theta} \le 1$ and the supremum is equal to $1/R$ (at $\theta = 0$). That is not good enough to show that the integral converges to zero.

Comment: @MartinR Doesn't $0\leq|f(z)|\leq\sup_{z\in\Gamma}|f(z)|$ via the estimation lemma along with the fact you mentioned confirm both the integrals convergence and that it converges to zero? (squeeze theorem maybe)

Comment: @AnthonyML: No, because the length of the arc is $\pi R$. The estimation lemma gives only that $|I| \le \frac 1R \cdot \pi R = \pi$.

Comment: @MartinR So more is needed to guarantee its convergence to zero then. In which case this is the main focus of my question given $e^{-R\sin\theta}\leq 1$

Comment: And this “more” can be obtained with Jordans lemma: $e^{-R\sin\theta}\leq e^{-2R\theta/\pi}$.

Comment: and $\pi R \sup|\frac{e^{-2R\theta / \pi}}{R}|\to0$ as $R\to\infty$ for sure. I'll delete the question/ keep it closed (thank you)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144926/discussion-between-martin-r-and-anthonyml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you should use the [Lebesgue convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) (a.k.a. dominated convergence): If $\Gamma_R$ denotes the upper semicircle of Radius $R>0$, then (skipping everything you already did)

$$\left|\int\limits_{\Gamma_R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz\right| \leq \cdots\leq \int\limits_0^\pi e^{-R\sin\theta}d\theta. \hspace{1cm}(*)$$

The family $(F_R)_{R>0}$ with $F_R : [0,\pi]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $\theta\longmapsto e^{-R\sin\theta}$ converges to $0$ pointwise almost everywhere on $[0,\pi]$ for $R\longrightarrow\infty$, and is dominated by the $L^1([0,\pi])$-function $\theta\longmapsto1$. Thus, the Lebesgue theorem can be applied and it follows that the integral on the right hand side of $(*)$ tends to $0$ for $R\longrightarrow 0$.

Alternatively (essentially doing the proof of the dominated convergence theorem by hand), for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $R>0$ so that $|F_R(\theta)| \leq\frac{\varepsilon}{\pi}$ for all $\theta\in I_\varepsilon:=[0+\frac{\varepsilon}{2},\pi-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}]$. For all other values, i.e. for $\theta\in J_\varepsilon:=(I_\varepsilon)^c = [0,\frac{\varepsilon}{2})\cup(\pi-\frac{\varepsilon}{2},\pi]$, we still can use that $|F_R(\theta)|\leq 1$, so:
$$\int\limits_0^\pi e^{-R\sin\theta}d\theta \leq \int\limits_{I_\varepsilon} \underbrace{F_R(\theta)}_{\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{\pi}}d\theta + \int\limits_{J_\varepsilon} \underbrace{F_R(\theta)}_{\leq 1} d\theta \leq \underbrace{\lambda(I_\varepsilon)}_{\leq \pi}\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{\pi} + \underbrace{\lambda(J_\varepsilon)}_{\leq 2\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}\cdot1 \leq 2\varepsilon$$

Here, $\lambda$ denotes the $1$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, or in this case just the "length" of a real interval, i.e. $\lambda([a,b])=b-a$.

Comment: It is much easier to  perform estimates if one integrates over a diamond-shaped  loop , an enlarged copy of $|y|= 1-|x|$, parametrized  so that $y$ is a linear function of $x$ on each leg Then the bounding integrand. can be evaluated exactly

Comment: @MathWonk In some situations this would be the preferred way of doing it, yes. But in this case, when it's only about an estimate - not the rate of how quickly the integral vanishes - it suffices to just use tools like dominated convergence to circumvent any calculations.

Comment: @Nuke_Gunray.FWIW. An elegant elementary alternative to Jordan's estimate is discussed in this article: A Simplification in Certain Contour Integrals Harold P. Boas and Eduardo Friedman The American Mathematical Monthly Vol. 84, No. 6 (Jun. - Jul., 1977), pp. 467-468

Basically they show that if you integrate over a large triangular loop then all the bounding integrands can be evaluated exactly by elementary methods.

Comment: @MathWonk I just read it, thanks for mentioning it!